# Is Vector in Cosine Similarity the same as vector in Physics?

Tags: cosine-distance

I'm new to Data Science. I'm trying to understand cosine similarity and it seems like the equation is about finding the distance between two vectors. From what I've Googled, a vector needs to have magnitude and direction. But in CS, it seems like it's a 1-dimensional array. Is vector in CS the same as vector in Physics? If so, what is the direction of a vector. And if a vector is like this `[1, 0, 1, 0]` what is the magnitude of this vector?

Comment: This explanation may help  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you ask specifically for the Cosine Similarity technique, it has magnitude and direction, and similar to a vector which is used in Physics, as Cosine Similarity deals with vectors in an inner product space.

[image]

So, the magnitude of vectors is exactly the same as the formula in Physics (summating over the squares of the vector elements.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same.

The array `[1, 0, 1, 0]` represents a vector in $4$ dimensional euclidean space ($\mathbb{R}^4$) with tails at `[0, 0 , 0 ,0]` and head at  `[1, 0, 1, 0]`. So your vector is "pointing" in the direction of your given set of coordinates.

This might be easier to visualize in $2$ dimensions: for example, the array `[1,0]` corresponds to the unit vector along the $x$-axis centered at the origin.